# How do I select a string that has a word begins with a capital letter with a regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

Say I have an array like this:

```
> names
=> ["John", "Van", "der", "and", "an", "the boys and John Smith"]
```

How do I just select `John`, `Van` and `the boys and John Smith` from that array?

I tried [this regex](http://www.rubular.com/r/dmfpfamNGe) but it misses the last string, which is the most tricky:

```
/^[A-Z]\w*/
```

What's the more complete approach, that may catch other instances where a word that is capitalized appears within the middle of a string that I may be missing?

**Edit 1**

Another string I would like it to be able to capture is: `John Van der Lyn`, where there is a name that has a word with a common letter within the first & last name.

Comment: match all strings with capitalised words or just capitalised names?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 I will settle for all strings with capitalised words, because I believe capitalised names is impossible. However, if you have a suggestion for capturing just capitalised names....do share because that's the ultimate goal.

Comment: `^(?=.*\b[A-Z]).*`

Comment: @revo That looks legit. Go ahead and add that as an answer with a brief description and I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Your regex would have worked if you remove the anchor at beginning of the string `/[A-Z]\w*/`

Comment: @marcamillion: I see you are still keeping the question open: the Edit1 sounds as a different question. I am not sure what you need exactly, but trying to expand my regex in the answer, try [`/\b(?=\p{Lu})(\p{L})*(?=.*\1)/`](http://www.rubular.com/r/DditpSmznb). Note that the first `John` and `Van` cannot be matched with this regex as the requirements seem to mutually exclude one another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex:

```
^(?=.*\b[A-Z]).*
```

This benefits from a positive lookahead. It checks if there is any word that starts with a capital letter in input string then matches whole thing.

Explanation:

```
^               # Assert beginning of subject string
(?=             # Construct a positive lookahead
    .*\b[A-Z]       # Match start of a capitalized word
)               # End of lookahead
.*              # If lookahead was successful, match whole subject string
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use a simple `\b\p{Lu}` that will find any uppercase Unicode letter that starts a word (as `\b` is a [**word boundary**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)):

```
def get_names(names)
  names.select{ |name| name[/\b\p{Lu}/] }
end

names = ["John", "Van", "der", "and", "an", "the boys and John Smith"]
puts get_names(names) # ['John', 'Van', 'the boys and John Smith']
```

See the [Ruby demo](http://ideone.com/tOfpIn)